# CORS error when i interact with Gsheet using JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api

I don't have much knowledge of JS, I am trying to send form data to google sheet..

Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw87iZhw2-wfyKSV7bGFr11_XkI9D9LjrBA6doLleozwTVoWojyqKX8J4-gR_Skbr_c/exec' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
formGform.html:48          POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw87iZhw2-wfyKSV7bGFr11_XkI9D9LjrBA6doLleozwTVoWojyqKX8J4-gR_Skbr_c/exec net::ERR_FAILED 200
(anonymous) @ formGform.html:48
formGform.html:48                  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
at HTMLFormElement. (formGform.html:48:13)

And this is my html & JS code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML form to Google Sheet</title>
</head>
 
<body>
    <h1 id="msg"></h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name' id="name"><br><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Email' id="email"><br><br>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder='Phone' id="phone"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" id="sub" >
    </form>
    <script>


        let form = document.querySelector("form");
        
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
           let nm=document.querySelector("#name").value
           let email=document.querySelector("#email").value
           let phone=document.querySelector("#phone").value
           console.log(nm)
            if(nm.length == 0)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('wrong name')
            }
            else if(email.length == 0)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('wrong email')
            }
            else if(phone.length == 0)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('wrong phone')
            }
            else{
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector("#sub").value = "Submiting..";
            let data = new FormData(form);
            fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw87iZhw2-wfyKSV7bGFr11_XkI9D9LjrBA6doLleozwTVoWojyqKX8J4-gR_Skbr_c/exec', {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: data
                })
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(data => {
                    document.querySelector("#msg").innerHTML = data;
                    document.querySelector("#sub").value = "Submit"
                });
            }
           
        })
    </script>
</body>
 
</html>
```

In google sheet AppScript i write this code

```
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fyED4wBoghr6Y6wor6h9FdU2iMhRCCb3c4tyIxKUmp4/edit#gid=0");
const sheet = sheets.getSheetByName("Gformsubmit");
function doPost(e) {
  let data = e.parameter;
  sheet.appendRow([data.name, data.email, data.phone]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code in another project and it works fine. Try to check if you didn't change some field name in your HTML form and if the target spreadsheet has the necessary permissions to EDIT and/or that the application is running on your account and that anyone can access it (even anonymous) since you are not sending a Bearer Token in the request.

Catching the error in Google Apps Script using TryCatch

```
function doPost(e) {
  let sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gSheetURL);
  let sheet = sheets.getSheetByName(gSheetName);
  try {
    let data = e.parameter;
    sheet.appendRow([data.name, data.email, data.phone]);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
  }
  catch (exception) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      error: `${exception.stack} ${exception.message}`,
      postData: e,
      params: e.parameter
    }))
  }
}
```

This way if you get an error you will not get the CORS message but the reason for the actual error. Remember that whenever you make a call to Google Apps Script from an external place, if any error not controlled by TryCatch occurs, an error of type 4XX will be returned and the browser will interpret it as a CORS error.